# Is there a way to keep a running line count between two templates using position()?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm using two different templates to pull various data for two separate groups of an XML file. Is there a way to keep a running line count between the two templates?

Right now, I am using `position()` function, but the position resets once the new template is called.

My output looks like this:

```
First template called:

1
2
3
4
5
6
<---Second template called -->
1
2
3
```

I want it to look like:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
<-- Second template called -->
7
8
9
```

Comment: you'll get best results by including small sample inputs, and your code. We have the output and your output requirement. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to keep a running line count between the two templates?

No. But you can define a variable counting the nodes processed by the first template, and add it to the result returned by the position() function in the second template.

No code, because no code was provided.